# PHP check if the first occurrence of an array exists in another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays

```
$setWords = array ('one','two','three');
$setSentences = array('There is one cloud in the sky', 'A dog has four legs' , 'There are three cars parked outside');
```

I tried the following but it didn't work.

```
if(array_intersect($setWords , $setSentences) == true) {
print_r($setSentences);
}
```

In this case it would be `There is one cloud in the sky` and `There are three cars parked outside`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I love `preg_grep`:

```
$result = preg_grep('/'.implode('|', $setWords).'/', $setSentences);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 2):

This won't work. The array_intersect function only checks values that are exactly the same. You need to manually run over the arrays and compare contents using the `strpos` function.

Something like this:

```
foreach( $setWords as $word ) {
  foreach( $setSentences as $sentence ) {
    if( strpos( $sentence, $word ) !== false ) {
      echo "found " . $word . " in " . $sentence . "<br />";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Excellent. I can't believe it was so simple :-)